# Working with specific service from interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

this question is for an app console and .NET framework 4.7

I got 1 interface

```cs
public interface IPrepareDataService<T> 
{
    string Name{ get; }
    IEnumerable<T> GetImportData();
}
```

And 3 classes from this interface

```cs
public class APrepareDataService : IPrepareDataService<T>
{  
    public string Name{ get => "A";  }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetImportData()
    {            
        return GetRecords<T>();
    }
}
    
public class BPrepareDataService : IPrepareDataService<T>
{  
    public string Name{ get => "B";  }
    
    public IEnumerable<T> GetImportData()
    {            
        return GetRecords<T>();
    }
}
    
public class CPrepareDataService : IPrepareDataService<T>
{  
    public string Name{ get => "C";  }
    
    public IEnumerable<T> GetImportData()
    {            
        return GetRecords<T>();
    }
}
```

T class can be different for every class.

```cs
public class AClass
{
    public string Name{ get; set;  }
    public string Desc{ get; set;  }
}
    
public class BClass
{
    public string Name{ get; set;  }
    public string Surname{ get; set;  }
}
    
public class CClass
{
    public string Name{ get; set;  }
    public int Age{ get; set;  }
}
```

In program.cs i've registered services of interface:

```cs
private static readonly ServiceProvider _serviceProvider =
    new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<IPrepareDataService<AClass>, APrepareDataService>()
    .AddSingleton<IPrepareDataService<BClass>, BDataService>()
    .AddSingleton<IPrepareDataService<CClass>, CPrepareDataService>()
```

Problem comes now, in Main function i get from config file a value that defines what service im gonna use:

```cs
var prepareDataService = _serviceProvider.GetServices<IPrepareDataService<AClass>>().First(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == ValueFromConfig.ToUpper());
```

Problem is that i have to set an specific class when i try to get service:

```cs
_serviceProvider.GetServices<IPrepareDataService<AClass>>
```

, so if ValueFromconfig = A, it's gonna work fine, but if it's B it doenst works in a right way.

Question is: is there any way to GetService for the interface related with the value in config if value = A Then interface for AClass, if B interface for BClass?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code as it is, does not compile, so it's unclear what you are trying to do. `public class APrepareDataService : IPrepareDataService<T>` is not valid, did you mean `public class APrepareDataService : IPrepareDataService<AClass>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this once, or at runtime multiple times.

To do it multiple times (And I think this is what you want), you can use the GetService overload to pass in a type rather than using the generic. Something like :

```
var configValue = "AClass";
var requiredType = configValue switch
{
    "AClass" => typeof(IPrepareDataService<AClass>),
};

_serviceProvider.GetService(requiredType);
```

To do it once (e.g. Once your app starts up, read the config, and then you are done), you would need to selectively bind the service collection.